# Channel creation fails after upgrading hyperledger fabric network

Tags: node.js, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I updated a development hyperledger fabric network from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4 and can no longer create channels or interact with the network because a channel policy fails that was not failing in v1.4.1

The following is what happens when I try to create a channel via node sdk

Errors from node sdk

```
error: Status: BAD_REQUEST
Info: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Errors from Orderer Docker container

```
[orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 00e [channel: farm] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.1:40866 because of error: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'farm', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

crypto-config section

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

Comment: Please mention what kind of transaction you are doing.

Comment: Channel creation- I have updated the questions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please set the logging level of the orderer to debug and for additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the fabric-samples configtx.yaml for v1.4.4 as a template I found the only difference was this `Capabilities` section

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there were some Channel Policy and Channel Capability changes in 1.4.3

I solved the problem by getting the configtx.yaml from first-network the 1.4.3 fabric-samples and applying my changes (org names etc) to that new yaml file.  Then generating a new genesis block etc.

Comment: Ok thanks Ill try that- it may solve the issue but I am still curious what the problem is

Comment: I did this and it worked- so thank you! Not sure if I can accept this as a valid answer to the question lol